# Use of std::function for function return

Tags: c++, c++11

I came across C++11 style of function pointer using std::function method.Following scenario works fine with older method of function pointer but fails with new thingie.

```
#include <functional>
using namespace std;
function<int(int,int)> arithmeticFcn;

int add(int x,int y)
{
return x + y;
}

arithmeticFcn getOperation(char op)
{
switch (op) {
case '+':
return add;
break;
default:
return add;
break;
}
}

int main()
{
int x = 10,y = 20;
char op1;
cin >> op1;
arithmeticFcn Fcn = getOperation(op1);
cout << Fcn(x,y) << endl;
return 0;
}
```

Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: `arithmeticFcn` doesn't name a type.

Comment: `return; break;`?! The `break` is never reached.

Comment: _"Following scenario [..] fails with new thingie."_ This is not an acceptable problem description.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Copy/paste approach to learning C++, at its best

Comment: I prefer the term Cargo Cult Programming. It has more pizzazz.

Comment: Not to add to the discontent with this question but I'd go read up on c++ a bit more . I'd recommend The C++ Programming Language by Stroustrup , effective c++ and more effective c++ before asking this community questions.

Comment: If you cannot reply that please do not add your suggestions and wasting others time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to go out on a limb and guess that you previously wrote:

```
typedef int arithmeticFcn(int, int);
```

and called this a function pointer.

It is not a function pointer. It was never a function pointer. You made `arithmeticFcn` a function *type*, which is how you were able to use it as you have done above.

But here:

```
function<int(int,int)> arithmeticFcn;
```

You are not creating a type. You are creating a functor, called `arithmeticFcn`.

I imagine you meant:

```
typedef function<int(int,int)> arithmeticFcn;
```